# How to get a toolbar to add bookmarks in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

On my laptop this works fine, but on my desktop I can't figure out the setting to allow for my bookmarks to be visible all the time in chrome.

When I say bookmarks, I mean right below the url textbox in chrome, there is another row where my bookmarks are visible.

It does show up when I click to open a new tab, but then it disappears.

Answer (score 4):

There's a hotkey for this: <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>. You can also right click on "Other bookmarks" and select "Always show booksmarks bar."

[image: toggle Chrome bookmarks bar]

Answer (score 1):

Other than what briankb said, you can also use the Chrome Prefences Screen for this

Go to your preference Page (Click On Wrench Icon => Preferences) and then tick "Always show the bookmarks bar"

[image]